# How does one keep track of all the components in a Java Application?

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I'm more interested in understanding how it's done in the real world.

I am building an application in Javafx where it is listening to `INPUT` within a webpage using webview. When the user clicks an input a new Button("Input Clicked") is created and added to a GridPane, at the bottom. The user can then click the button and a dialog will appear for information, like the inputs ID, Class, Value, etc.

If a webpage has 10+ inputs, how does one keep track of all the new Button()s created? Do I write to a file? Do I create an arraylist? If so, what if the user closes the application? How do I recreate the GridPane, almost like a File->Save feature?

I've attached an image of the application. As you can see, I have clicked the google search INPUT 4 times, 4 buttons were created. Each one needs to be unique. If I close the application, it needs to recreate it.

the code is simply

```
mainGrid.add(new Button("Input Clicked",IncrementCol,IncrementRow);
```

[Example](http://postimg.org/image/6h95fufdl/)

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your application without a picture.  Generally, I create a class for each panel.  Sometimes, I create a class for a piece of a panel if the panel is complicated.  When creating a GUI, you should use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to separate concerns.

Comment: If you are trying to save information for a specific user I would recommend using some sort of data storage. Be it a file, database or local key/value store. However you will still need to map these 'created buttons' to a specific user/session so keep that in mind as well when designing the data structure you will use.

Comment: Your definition of "keep track of all components" is really hard to understand. Do you want to persist/save data? Do you want to log something? Debug? Monitor?

Comment: I wan to be able to use the component. for example, if user added 4 buttons and then the user wants to delete one, how would I know which he/she chose to delete?

Comment: Your question is way too vague, but it seems like you need to create some representation of the *data* in your application (a list of URLs? not sure exactly). Then your UI is just a view of those data. Persist the data, delete items from the list, etc, and just arrange that the view always updates when the data change.

Comment: I guess I can add a setOnAction event when it's created. Delete was just an example. What if I wanted to close the application, how would I open to the same state?

Comment: Persist the data when you close, read it back in when you start, and create the view based on the data (which you would already have coded anyway).

Comment: I think you need to provide a specific example, with a [MCVE] if you want an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of keeping track of your input controls is through a pattern called "[Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)". The state of the input controls is captured in the Model, which you can persist and then restore later.

Something like this. The `UI` class combines the `View` (the `JTextField` and `JLabel`, etc.) and the `Controller` (`ActionListener`). You might want to separate these into different classes in a large enough UI. The `Model` class holds all the state, that the `Controller` shifts between the `View` and the `Model`.

This allows you to keep track of the things in the UI.

```
public UI extends JFrame {
    private Model model;
    private JTextField fn;
    private JTextField ln;
    private JLabel n;

    public JFrame(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        fn = JTextField(model.getFirstName());
        ln = JTextField(model.getLastName());
        n = new JLabel(model.getFullName());
        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton s = new JButton("Save");
        JButton r = new JButton("Restore");
        b.setActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                model.setFirstName(fn.getText());
                model.setLastName(ln.getText());
                n.setText(model.getFullName());
            }
        });
        s.setActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                model.save();  
            }
        });
        r.setActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                model.load();  
                fn.setText(model.getFirstName());
                ln.setText(model.getLastName());
                n.setText(model.getFullName());                  
            }
        });
        add(fn);
        add(ln);
        add(l);
        add(b);
        add(s);
        add(r);
    }
}

public class Model {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    private fullName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName; update(); }
    public String getLastName() { return firstName; }
    public void setLastName(String firstName) { this.firstName; update(); }
    public String getFullName() { return fullName; }
    public void update() { this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName }

    public void save() {
        try(PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:/temp/test.txt"))) {
           w.println(firstName);
           w.println(lastName);
        }
    }

    public void load() {
       try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("c:/temp/test.txt"))) {
          firstName = s.next();
          lastName = s.next();
          update();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense. But what if the JTextField are not fixed? What if I need to create new and delete JTextField on the fly? How do you implement that in the model?

Comment: In the model, probably as a list. Some logic in the Controller will decide that the View needs a new JTextField and needs to tell the Model to add something to the list. Then it's the Controller's job to know how to shuffle data between the list of values and the JTextField the item in the list belongs to. Maybe you can keep a list of JTextField objects in the Controller? Just remember how the responsibilities are divided between Model, View and Controller and it should make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your Buttons/GridPane is Serializable, you could choose an also serializable list implementation (like ArrayList) and then serialize that into a file whenever the user adds a button or closes the application. Deserialization then allows for easy reconstruction of the saved state.

Answer (score 0):

Create model objects, like simple JavaBean, to contain the state and data.  These objects should not be JavaFC classes, just simple classes you create.  You would serialize these to a file as you see fit.  I wrote a lot of code for doing this for JavaFX applications and I can attest that it is possible to write to files on a web deployed JavaFX, though there were some hoops to jump.

You can store the saved objects in memory in custom domain specific Context or Manager singletons (e.g. `AccountManager.getInstance()` or `AccountnContext.getInstance()`).  These singleton objects would query for the serialized objects upon startup or on request.  You can have a serialization class that manages all the sterilization of objects to disk.  Maybe it takes the name of the file and the object type and would either save it or retrieve it.  The singletons would hold and provide access to the JavaBean objects.

EDIT:  Just to add to @sh0rug0ru's answer, my answer is centered on the Model aspect of the MVC.  The Model is responsible for containing the state, values, and sterilization of the domain specific objects.